# webparts SQL server tables

Tags: sql, sharepoint, web-parts

My new project requires me to create some 12 SQL tables and build some web parts in SharePoint 2010, to perform CRUD operation on the tables. One main table has around 25 columns and the rest of the tables has 2 or 3 columns and some are just join tables.

The main requirement is the when someone adds or changes the data in the tables it should not be available to everyone.  A manager must approve the data before it is updated in the table.

I don’t have much experience in SQL or SharePoint for that matter, so can someone let me know how this can be done.

And is web parts the best way to do the CRUD operations, or can I use BCS which I feel is easy?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Access Web App. In SharePoint 2010 it will create lists as underlying data "tables", you can create workflows on these lists.

If you have limited experience in SQL or SharePoint this will offer you a GUI driven solution with very little or no coding requirements.

Access Web Apps offer a more versatile BCS-type solution. It is more bulky, but it is far easier to develop your solution and you can still leverage your SharePoint permissions and workflows.